# Flex drawing example error

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I am new to flex and i am trying to run the code for flex drawing application example given at following path:
http://www.flashcomguru.com/components/flex_whiteboard/whiteboard_demo/srcview/index.html

But I get the following error at the compile time:

''Unable to locate specified base class 'Whiteboard.WhiteboardManager' for component class 'Whiteboard.Whiteboard'.''

Please someone suggest me that why it is coming and how i can overcome this.I am using Flash player version 10 and flex 3.0 sdk for the project.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the WhiteBoard.swc library in your project. If you're using Eclipse/Flex Builder go to project properties -> flex build path -> library path -> add swc. Or moving it to the libs folder should be enough.
The sources for the component are not included in that demo as it is not a free component. I didn't see a demo version either, so unless you buy it, you probably won't be able to run those sources locally.

Comment: Ya I guess the same..
Thanks for the help and such a nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your source paths aren't set up correctly. Have a read of this article to see how source paths are set up

http://www.cove.org/ape/quickstart_fb.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion James, but i have created a new project in flex builder 3 and then the in the source folder i put all the given codes.Then at compile time i get this error.
Please suggest me if i am wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hang on... looking at the source, that class is missing.  You may need to email the guy that created it to see if he can send it to you.